# How to create transparent footer bar using css

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have JQM footer bar with text and icon. I need it to be transparent but the icon should be viewable. The background listview should be visible using css, like in iOS-7.

Comment: its footer. and use css opacity for your footer element

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the code below and [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZjTfD/)

Place any content in your footer or any container. Use opacity ( supported IE8+) for all of them and handle it using javascript or css on hover with some transition effect.

```
footer{width: 500px;
background: #999;
opacity: 0.4; // or use rgba() where a opacity.
}

footer:hover{
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```